# Mongo show collections on remote server works on windows but stucks on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I am in a strange situation with mongodb remote connection.
I have a Mongo DB on an ec2 instance and has been configured with password auth.

When I connect it and browse collections on a windows platform it works fine but when I try to do the same on Amazon ec2(Ubuntu) it just gets stuck.
Though I am able to connect on Ubuntu instance but when I try to run the commmand show collections.The server just hangs.

Windows-

```
E:\check\scheduler\trunk>mongo 54.xxx.xx.xx:27017/vdb -u vadmin -p db@dummypass
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: 54.xxx.xx.xx:27017/vdb
> use vdb;
switched to db vdb
> show collections;
activity
user
adminpush
adminuserlog
friend
demo
addressbook
branddemovideo
```

Ubuntu(Ec2 Instance )

```
ubuntu@ip-10-146-147-102:~$ mongo 54.xxx.xx.xx:27017/vdb -u vadmin -p 'db@dummypass'
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: 54.xxx.xx.xx:27017/vdb
> show databases;
admin   0.078125GB
local   0.078125GB
vdb    1.49951171875GB
> use vdb;
switched to db vdb
> show collections;

Its Just Stuck over here.
```

Finally after some time I got to see an error-

```
Mon Oct 20 19:52:51.949 Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 54.xxx.xx.xx:27017
Mon Oct 20 19:52:51.954 SocketException: remote: 54.xxx.xx.xx:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [54.xxx.xx.xx:27017]
Mon Oct 20 19:52:51.954 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Mon Oct 20 19:52:51.955 Error: error doing query: failed at src/mongo/shell/query.js:78
Mon Oct 20 19:52:51.955 trying reconnect to 54.xxx.xx.xx:27017
Mon Oct 20 19:52:51.969 reconnect 54.xxx.xx.xx:27017 ok
```

Mongo Logs given below-

Local Server

```
ubuntu@ip-172-xx-x-xx:/var/log/mongodb$ tail -f mongodb.log
2014-10-20T20:34:50.621+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
2014-10-20T20:39:50.633+0530 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:36 virt:342
2014-10-20T20:39:50.633+0530 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-10-20T20:39:50.633+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
2014-10-20T20:44:50.645+0530 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:36 virt:342
2014-10-20T20:44:50.645+0530 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-10-20T20:44:50.645+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
2014-10-20T20:49:50.658+0530 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:36 virt:342
2014-10-20T20:49:50.658+0530 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-10-20T20:49:50.658+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

Remote Server-

```
2014-10-20T20:55:05.688+0530 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 54.xxx.xxx.xxx:57881 #42 (11 connections now open)
2014-10-20T20:55:05.692+0530 [conn42]  authenticate db: vdb { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "vadmin", key: "xxx" }
2014-10-20T20:55:36.039+0530 [conn13] query vdb.video query: { query: { videoType: 5, viewType: 1, status: { $nin: [ 2, 5, 3 ] }, location.regionId: 2, frameHeight: { $gt: 0 } }, orderby: { popularRating: -1 } } planSummary: IXSCAN { location.regionId: 1 }, IXSCAN { location.regionId: 1 } cursorid:86724525795 ntoreturn:3 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2892 nscannedObjects:2892 keyUpdates:0 numYields:1 locks(micros) r:232390 nreturned:3 reslen:8101 116ms
2014-10-20T20:55:36.087+0530 [conn9] query vdb.video query: { query: { videoType: 5, viewType: 1, status: { $nin: [ 2, 5, 3 ] }, location.regionId: 2, frameHeight: { $gt: 0 } }, orderby: { popularRating: -1 } } planSummary: IXSCAN { location.regionId: 1 }, IXSCAN { location.regionId: 1 } cursorid:86710924707 ntoreturn:3 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2892 nscannedObjects:2892 keyUpdates:0 numYields:1 locks(micros) r:162238 nreturned:3 reslen:8101 112ms
```

Comment: What do the logs of the mongo server say?

Comment: Finally I resolved it.
I was working in a VPC and had to use Private IP to connect to remote mongo as well as mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved it. I was working in a VPC and had to use Private IP to connect to remote mongo as well as mysql.